# PHP Error with Channel Field Group

Tags: channel, custom-fields

I am getting a PHP Error, when I go to publish > Channel(name). I have this assigned to what I call the 'master' field group (master) it has 15 fields. I set up a test field group and assigned it to the channel and NO ERROR message. Can I fix this without rebuilding the master field group? I can not find out if there is a limited to the Number of field group I can have.

**Here are the 3 PHP Error I get:**

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 0
Filename: models/grid_model.php
Line Number: 496

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning
 Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output    started at /home/jbreen/dev-sbco/sbco/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
 Filename: core/Common.php
 Line Number: 475

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'col_id_' in 'order clause'
SELECT * FROM (`exp_channel_grid_field_15`) WHERE `entry_id` IN (0) ORDER BY `col_id_` asc
Filename: models/grid_model.php
Line Number: 413
```

Comment: PHP and MySQL errors should not occur, and aren't indications of user error. I would suggest filing a bug report or support ticket with EllisLab to discover why this happened, and to prevent it in the future.

Comment: Have you by chance upgraded EE recently?? You don't detail when the error first occured, why it might be occuring... From the looks of it, it looks like it's mucked up creating one of your grid fields (field ID 15), as it's missing data columns from `exp_channel_grid_field_15`...

Comment: We're having exactly the same problem with the grid field. However, we simply added a new Assets field to a grid and then removed it without entering any data. Then it threw the errors...help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it looks like the issue is in the channel field with the ID 15, and this field is in fact a grid type.

I've posed a few questions for you above, however as a "first answer" could you try going to your Channel fields, removing **just** field with ID of 15 (grid) and recreating please?

That's what the error is saying, field 15 has got issues in the DB. Another question, have you recently tried updating a server with your local copy? it could be (cant be sure, lack of info) that you created a grid field on your local/dev (which created the table and columns) and then migrated the data to a different server, and lost some of your field setups...

Comment: Thanks for the answer 'tick' seeingis. Can I ask what did it turn out to be exactly? We speculate on a few causes here and it might help others (even if the answer is correct) if you could comment on what exactly caused the issue .